# Change Material when collision than change color by color picker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have different objects with different material , and one box object object without material, now I can change the box material when I grab different object collide the box by following code

```
public class Target : MonoBehaviour{
```

public Material currentTargetMaterial;

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //Check for a match with the specific tag on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //get the original mesrender 
        MeshRenderer mesRender = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        //from original meshrender to get the original material
        Material oldMaterial = mesRender.material;
        //the gameobject who clooide with
        GameObject who = collision.gameObject;
        //get rhe collide object's meshrender
        MeshRenderer sourceRender = who.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        //get the collider's object's material
        Material sourceMaterial = sourceRender.material;
        //change material
        mesRender.material = sourceMaterial;
        currentTargetMaterial = sourceMaterial;
        Debug.Log("NOW IS " + currentTargetMaterial);
    }
```

and I have another class call Applycolor to handle apply color to box , I try to use

```
public Material currentTargetMaterial;
```

to pass the material to Applycolor class by following code

```
public class Applycolor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FlexibleColorPicker fcp;
    public Material material;
    Target targetObject = new Target();
   
   
    private void Update()
    {
       Material rightnow =  targetObject.nowMaterial();
       Debug.Log("current is " +  rightnow );
        material = rightnow;
        material.color = fcp.color;
    }
```

but I can't get the material , I'm a beginner , please help :(

Answer (score 0):

sorry , so stupid , I add these lines in ApplyColor class and it's solved

```
{
    public FlexibleColorPicker fcp;
    public Material material;
    GameObject box;
    Material boxMaterial;
    
private void Update()
{
    box = GameObject.Find("targetBox");
    boxMaterial = box.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    material = boxMaterial;
    material.color = fcp.color;
}
```